# Converting values to Dates in column

Tags: array, vba

I'm not happy about my code, but is the better way that I find, 
I'm not happy because I see that there are many code repetitions and when any change is easy to make mistakes. Do you think you can do better?
Any suggestions are welcome

```
Sub ConvDateD(c As Integer)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lrw As Long, i As Long, NrArr As Integer
Dim ArrVal As Variant, tempArr() As Variant
Dim MaxVal As Long, StartVal As Long, RangeVal As Long
Dim avvio As Date, arresto As Date, tempo As Date
avvio = Now
StartVal = 2
MaxVal = 65000
RangeVal = 65000
lrw = ActiveSheet().Cells(1, c).End(xlDown).Row

If (lrw / MaxVal) - Int(lrw / MaxVal) > 0 Then
    NrArr = (lrw / MaxVal) + 1
Else
    NrArr = lrw / MaxVal
End If

If NrArr = 1 Then
    ReDim ArrVal(StartVal To lrw)
    For i = StartVal To lrw
        If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then

            ArrVal(i) = Cells(i, c)
        Else
            Select Case Len(Cells(i, c)) 
                Case 8
                    ArrVal(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                Case 6
                    ArrVal(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
            End Select
        End If
NextX:
    Next i

Else
    For a = 1 To NrArr
    Select Case a
    Case 1
        ReDim tempArr1(2 To MaxVal)
        For i = StartVal To MaxVal
            If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then
                tempArr1(i) = Cells(i, c)
            Else
                Select Case Len(Cells(i, c))
                    Case 8
                        tempArr1(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                    Case 6
                        tempArr1(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
        Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr1)

            StartVal = MaxVal + 1
           If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
    Case 2
        ReDim tempArr2(StartVal To MaxVal)
        For i = StartVal To MaxVal
            If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then
                tempArr2(i) = Cells(i, c)
            Else
                Select Case Len(Cells(i, c))
                    Case 8
                        tempArr2(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                    Case 6
                        tempArr2(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
        Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr2)
           StartVal = MaxVal + 1
           If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
    Case 3
        ReDim tempArr3(StartVal To MaxVal)
        For i = StartVal To MaxVal
            If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then
                tempArr1(i) = Cells(i, c)
            Else
                Select Case Len(Cells(i, c))
                    Case 8
                        tempArr3(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                    Case 6
                        tempArr3(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
       Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr3)
            StartVal = MaxVal + 1
           If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
    Case 4
        ReDim tempArr4(StartVal To MaxVal)
        For i = StartVal To MaxVal
            If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then
                tempArr1(i) = Cells(i, c)
            Else
                Select Case Len(Cells(i, c))
                    Case 8
                        tempArr4(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                    Case 6
                        tempArr4(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
       Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr4)
            StartVal = MaxVal + 1
           If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
    Case 5
        ReDim tempArr5(StartVal To MaxVal)
        For i = StartVal To MaxVal
            If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then
                tempArr1(i) = Cells(i, c)
            Else
                Select Case Len(Cells(i, c)) ' to check YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD
                    Case 8
                        tempArr5(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                    Case 6
                        tempArr5(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
       Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr5)
            StartVal = MaxVal + 1
           If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
    Case 6
        ReDim tempArr6(StartVal To MaxVal)
        For i = StartVal To MaxVal
            If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then
                tempArr1(i) = Cells(i, c)
            Else
                Select Case Len(Cells(i, c)) ' to check YYYYMMDD or YYMMDD
                    Case 8
                        tempArr6(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                    Case 6
                        tempArr6(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
       Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr6)
            StartVal = MaxVal + 1
           If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
    End Select
Next a
End If
arresto = Now
tempo = arresto - avvio
Debug.Print tempo
Columns(c).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY;@"
Columns(c).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you describe what your code is trying to accomplish? It's an awful lot easier than trying to figure it out from the code.

Answer (score 1):

### Naming

Before anyone (including future you) can fix your code. Or extend it. Or modify it. Or change it in any way, they have to first understand what it is **currently** doing (and why). As such, code should be written for other people to read and understand. The most important aspect of this is naming things usefully.

Names should be **descriptive**. Then they should be **unambiguous**. **Only then** should they be Concise.

---

`c As Integer`

What is `c`? I've no idea. I see it used a lot for `Cells( ... , c )`. So, I'm assuming it's a Column Index. By the looks of your code, it is the column your sub is working on. As such, why not call it `targetColumn`? Takes negligibly more time to read, and a lot less time to understand.

---

What is `lrw`? Again, no idea. I **think** it's meant to be the `lastRow` but I'm not sure.

---

`NrArr`? Something to do with arrays. Maybe. But what? Oh, `numberOfArrays`. Much easier if you just name it properly in the first place.

---

`MaxVal`? Ok, a maximum value, but **of what?** Still no idea. If I hadn't seen your previous question, I'm not sure I would've figure it out.

---

Compare these, which takes less time to **understand**?

```
Sub ConvDateD(c As Integer)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lrw As Long, i As Long, NrArr As Integer
Dim ArrVal As Variant, tempArr() As Variant
Dim MaxVal As Long, StartVal As Long, RangeVal As Long
Dim avvio As Date, arresto As Date, tempo As Date
avvio = Now
StartVal = 2
MaxVal = 65000
RangeVal = 65000
lrw = ActiveSheet().Cells(1, c).End(xlDown).Row

If (lrw / MaxVal) - Int(lrw / MaxVal) > 0 Then
    NrArr = (lrw / MaxVal) + 1
Else
    NrArr = lrw / MaxVal
End If
```

or

```
Dim startDate As Date
startDate = Now

Const START_ROW As Long = 2 '/ +1 for headers
Const MAX_ITEMS_PER_ARRAY As Long = 65000 '/ due to integer size limit

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(1, targetColumn).End(xlDown).Row

Dim numArraysRequired As Long
numArraysRequired = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(lastRow / MAX_ITEMS_PER_ARRAY, 0)
```

Name things **descriptively**. Declare them **close to where they're actually used**. Add some **whitespace**. It'll make your code so much easier to work with, now and in the future.

---

### Refactoring

The other key to great code is taking one big thing, and separating it into lots of little things. Take this for instance:

```
    If IsDate(Cells(i, c)) Then

        ArrVal(i) = Cells(i, c)
    Else
        Select Case Len(Cells(i, c)) 
            Case 8
                ArrVal(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 4), Mid(Cells(i, c), 5, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
            Case 6
                ArrVal(i) = DateSerial(Left(Cells(i, c), 2), Mid(Cells(i, c), 3, 2), Right(Cells(i, c), 2))
        End Select
    End If
```

What's happening here? You're taking a `Range` object, and converting its' contents into a `Datevalue`. You repeat this code **lots of times**. If it changes, you'll have to change **all** of them.

Instead, write a `Function` called `DatevalueFromRange` which, unsurprisingly, takes a `Range` object and converts it into a `datevalue` and call that instead. This one change takes your code from **126 lines** to **just 59**. It looks like this:

```
    If NrArr = 1 Then
        ReDim ArrVal(StartVal To lrw)
        For i = StartVal To lrw
            ArrVal(i) = DatevalueFromRange(Cells(i, c))
NextX:
        Next i

    Else
        For a = 1 To NrArr
        Select Case a
        Case 1
            ReDim tempArr1(2 To MaxVal)
            For i = StartVal To MaxVal
                ArrVal(i) = DatevalueFromRange(Cells(i, c))
            Next i
            Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr1)

                StartVal = MaxVal + 1
               If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
        Case 2
            ReDim tempArr2(StartVal To MaxVal)
            For i = StartVal To MaxVal
                ArrVal(i) = DatevalueFromRange(Cells(i, c))
            Next i
            Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr2)
               StartVal = MaxVal + 1
               If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
        Case 3
            ReDim tempArr3(StartVal To MaxVal)
            For i = StartVal To MaxVal
                ArrVal(i) = DatevalueFromRange(Cells(i, c))
            Next i
           Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr3)
                StartVal = MaxVal + 1
               If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
        Case 4
            ReDim tempArr4(StartVal To MaxVal)
            For i = StartVal To MaxVal
                ArrVal(i) = DatevalueFromRange(Cells(i, c))
            Next i
           Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr4)
                StartVal = MaxVal + 1
               If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
        Case 5
            ReDim tempArr5(StartVal To MaxVal)
            For i = StartVal To MaxVal
                ArrVal(i) = DatevalueFromRange(Cells(i, c))
            Next i
           Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr5)
                StartVal = MaxVal + 1
               If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
        Case 6
            ReDim tempArr6(StartVal To MaxVal)
            For i = StartVal To MaxVal
                ArrVal(i) = DatevalueFromRange(Cells(i, c))
            Next i
           Range(Cells(StartVal, c), Cells(MaxVal, c)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(tempArr6)
                StartVal = MaxVal + 1
               If StartVal + RangeVal < lrw Then MaxVal = StartVal + RangeVal Else MaxVal = lrw
        End Select
    Next a
```

Which looks **awfully** like some kind of `Loop` logic. Like this:

```
    Dim currentRow As Long
    currentRow = START_ROW - 1

    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim printRange As Range

    Dim finalIndex As Long

    Dim arrayCounter As Long
    For arrayCounter = 1 To numArraysRequired

        If arrayCounter = numArraysRequired Then
            finalIndex = lastRow Mod MAX_ITEMS_PER_ARRAY '/ remainder left over in final loop
        Else
            finalIndex = MAX_ITEMS_PER_ARRAY
        End If

        ReDim ArrVal(1 To finalIndex)

        Set startCell = Cells(currentRow + 1, targetColumn)

        For i = 1 To finalIndex
            currentRow = currentRow + i
            Set currentCell = Cells(currentRow, targetColumn)
            ArrVal(i) = DatevalueFromRange(currentCell)
        Next i

        Set printRange = Range(startCell, currentCell)
        printRange = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrVal)

    Next arrayCounter
```

---

### Bring It Together

Now we can condense your whole sub into a very understandable, easy to use, couple of methods:

```
Sub ConvertDatesInColumn(ByVal targetColumn As Long)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim startTime As DateTime
    startTime = Now

    Const START_ROW As Long = 2 '/ +1 for headers
    Const MAX_ITEMS_PER_ARRAY As Long = 65000 '/ due to integer size limit

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(1, targetColumn).End(xlDown).Row

    Dim numArraysRequired As Long
    numArraysRequired = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(lastRow / MAX_ITEMS_PER_ARRAY, 0)

    Dim currentRow As Long
    currentRow = START_ROW - 1

    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim printRange As Range

    Dim finalIndex As Long

    Dim arrayCounter As Long
    For arrayCounter = 1 To numArraysRequired

        If arrayCounter = numArraysRequired Then
            finalIndex = lastRow Mod MAX_ITEMS_PER_ARRAY '/ remainder left over in final loop
        Else
            finalIndex = MAX_ITEMS_PER_ARRAY
        End If

        ReDim ArrVal(1 To finalIndex)

        Set startCell = Cells(currentRow + 1, targetColumn)

        For i = 1 To finalIndex
            currentRow = currentRow + i
            Set currentCell = Cells(currentRow, targetColumn)
            ArrVal(i) = DatevalueFromRange(currentCell)
        Next i

        Set printRange = Range(startCell, currentCell)
        printRange = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrVal)

    Next arrayCounter

    With targetSheet.Columns(targetColumn)
        .NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY;@"
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    Debug.Print "Time Taken: " & Now - startTime

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function DatevalueFromRange(ByRef inputRange As Range) As Date

    Dim dateValue As Date

    Dim rangeValue As Variant
    rangeValue = inputRange.Value

    If IsDate(rangeValue) Then

        dateValue = rangeValue

    Else

        Dim rangeText As String
        rangeText = inputRange.Text

        If Len(rangeText) = 8 Then dateValue = DateSerial(Left(rangeText, 4), Mid(rangeText, 5, 2), Right(rangeText, 2))
        If Len(rangeText) = 6 Then dateValue = DateSerial(Left(rangeText, 2), Mid(rangeText, 3, 2), Right(rangeText, 2))

    End If

    DatevalueFromRange = dateValue

End Function
```

---

Comment: a great big thank you, first of all because your answer was a little programming course. Thank also for the 3 bug in your code: 1th         missing "set" on startCell = Cells(currentRow + 1, targetColumn), 2th currentRow = currentRow + i will be currentRow = currentRow + 1 3th after run your code (updated ;-) )you retreive one record more. I tried your code with 390K record, it play on 11 seconds, @Ambie on SO suggest me one code that run on 3 seconds.

Comment: @fabrizio Writing fast(er) code is **easy**. Teaching people how to write code that is **useful**, that's a lot harder. My code here isn't an end product, it's there to demonstrate how to write code better. Actually writing a new program, that's up to you.